# Как по клику изменять спрайт по кругу итерируя массив?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

У меня есть 6 спрайтов ***( land; land_(brake1); land_(brake2); land_(brake3); и т.д.)*** Надо чтобы при клике спрайт ***land*** поменялся на ***land_(brake1)***. Если ещё раз кликнуть, то из ***land_(brake1)*** в ***land_(brake2)*** и т.д. Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А мне вопрос понравился. Не потому что сложно в реализации, а потому что такая ситуация заставляет обычно писать много "пустого" кода как в ответе Slavik (что не значит что его ответ плохой, просто плохочитабельный. Лично мне пришло сначала то же решение что и ему в голову, но я от него отказался из-за громоздкости)

Вот это должно сработать

```
private int _currSpriteIndex = 0;
private Sprite[] _sprites;
private SpriteRenderer _renderer;

void OnClick() {
    UpdateSprite();        
}

void UpdateSprite() {
    _renderer.sprite = _sprites[_currSpriteIndex++ % _sprites.Length];
}
```

Comment: а  я  без  деления   сделал  )))

Comment: @Slavik А здесь нету деления. Здесь есть остача от деления)

Comment: это  и  есть  деление

Comment: а после  него   еще  и  умножение )

Comment: @Splashny уточняй здесь в коментариях

Comment: @Andrew   или   остаток  от деления  как  по  другому  вычисляется ??

Comment: @Andrew   да  забей  вон чувак  ниже написал что мой вариант говно, так что ты выиграл

Comment: Понятия не имею как оно реализуется. Очень часто ты смотришь и представляешь себе одну реализацию, а под капотом ты видишь абсолютно иную, весьма сложную и значительно более оптимальную чем ты себе представлял с самого начала. Так что не изучая сортов Шарпа невозможно утверждать что это реализовано именно так. И тем более, нельзя утверждать "а я сделал это без...." когда в коде это самое "...." отсутствует ;)

Comment: @Slavik Я "выиграл" не потому, что быстрее или оптимальнее, а потому, что код короче и читабельнее. "оптимизация"(скорости) кода должна быть не на всякий случай, а по мере необходимости. В большинстве случаев краткость + читабельность кода значительно важнее "оптимальности" - наоборот это скорее исключение, чем правило. Если бы оптимальность играла на столько важную роль, все продолжали бы писать на ассемблере) А без объективных замеров или инвестигейта сорцов Шарпа еще весьма сложно сказать какой путь оптимальнее - твой или мой. Это так, к слову.

Comment: @Slavik Я, даже, практически уверен что у процессора есть специальная аппаратная поддержка этой операции и это не нужно обчислять кодом вручную. И если так и есть, то операции деления там и в помине нет)

Comment: @Andrew ну ты с этой стороны смотришь. а я считаю что лучше на пару строчек написать больше, а работало чтобы быстрее. Ну щас да, допустим прирост не важен, а пускай у него будет тысячу таких скриптов, которые обрабатывают это нажатие таким же макаром, вот тут уже заметнее будет. А мой код что не читаем или что ??

Comment: может быть и нету, но мы не знаем наверняка, есть  ли там такая поддержка

Comment: @Andrew Я совсем не шарю в программированию, поэтому был бы очень благодарен если бы вы объяснили некоторые детали. Если я просто скопирую и вставлю этот код он ведь не будет работать? Если это так, объясните пожалуйста куда вставлять/заменять названия спрайтов

Comment: 1. Вот когда будет 1000 скриптов, тогда и нужно усложнять. Потому что в 999 ситуациях из 1000 не будет 1000 скриптов этих. 2. повторюсь: реально неясно какой путь быстрее. Ты говоришь что твой, но практикой доказать не можешь. Вот я чесно не знаю какой код быстрее будет. Вполне вероятно что и мой. Потому что ты мыслишь буквальной математической реализацией, не зная что это может быть апаратно реализовано или что это может быть реализовано какими-то битовыми операциями и тогда мой код будет дешевле для компьютера раза в 2 :) Ты просто утверждаешь что твой код быстрее просто потому что потому.

Comment: 3. Можешь сделать тесты, сделать разогрев процессора, сравнить скорость выполнения твоего и моего кода и посмотреть для начала какой код быстрее. И тогда дискуссия хотя бы будет хоть чем-либо подкреплена.

Comment: @Splashny  присвой названия всех спрайтов в "_sprites" и все будет работать

Comment: @Andrew больше ничего не надо изменять, верно?

Comment: @Splashny понятия не имею. Наверное.  Может я чего-то не учел, может учел все. Я дал реализацию того что просилось, как именно ее в код встроить - это уже твоя задача. Я не могу писать весь код вместо тебя. Я вообще этот код писал без запуска вижуалки а просто из головы -- может, даже, в этом коде я где-то букву пропустил.

Comment: @Andrew так я ж не с проста говорю это,   возьми да замерь если сомневаешься

Comment: @Slavik c твоей категоричности видно что ты подвержен вот этому когнитивному искажению: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Эффект_Даннинга_—_Крюгера . Ты не знаешь наверняка как это реализовано внутри шарпа -- есть ли у процессора команда остачи от деления или, может, что операция в шарпе реализована через какие-то битовые операции, но при этом наверняка знаешь что твой код быстрее. Это, даже, мило, в какой-то степени. Дискуссия окончена.

Comment: @Andrew так я ж предлагаю тебе измерить

Comment: Я не был категоричен нигде что мой код быстрее. Потому что я не знаю этого) Но замерять предложил тебе я, а не ты мне) Хорошего дня

Comment: @Slavik Я перекусил, настроение похорошело и не поленился и проверил. На релизном билде при 100000000 повторениях с присвоением в новое значение листа (что бы оптимизатор не похерил тест) `my: 1757 yours: 1558` . Условно исполнение твоей операции быстрее на 200ms / 100000000 = 0.000002ms для одного вызова метода. Ни в одной жизненной ситуации эта оптимизация не окажется полезной при вызове по клике мышкой. Даже если на сцене будет мильйон таких скриптов висеть. Поздравляю, вы получили награду "оптимизатор" :)

Comment: @Andrew ну всёравно

Comment: "Все равно" дадут по ушам за такой код на рабочем месте)

Comment: быстрее же )   тут  доля милисекунды, там доля, вот так накопил и на пару кадров в секунду )

Comment: та  не   угорай  никто там  не  даст

Comment: На каких пару кадров?) Ты и на сотую долю кадра не накопил)

Comment: чем  он   плох  то ??   читаемость то

Comment: я  ж  говорю,  тут   доля  ,  там   гденибудь  еще  доля,    так  и  копится .  а  ты  как  думал

Comment: как   дед  говорит "наехал  тут  на  ямку, там на ямку ",  и  влип  на  ремонт

Comment: естественно ща  такие  процессоры что им  пофигу  всё,      но всё  равно приятно гдето   ускорить

Comment: та  вообще  не  знаю  у  меня  постоянно крыша  едет,  постоянно    боюсь  что  ща  напишу   гдето лишнюю операцию .  и  лагать  начнет,  не  знаю  чето такая  параноя    у  меня

Comment: @Andrew   а как  ты  время  засекаешь , скоко  оно выполнялось ??

Comment: Stopwatch, конечно же. Другими встроенными в шарп инструментами делать это бессмысленно. Главное замерять на релизе, а не дебаге иначе мой вариант окажется в 2 раза лучше твоего :) Но вообще под такое по хорошему нужно специальный бенчмарк использовать - вроде BenchmarkDotNet.

Comment: @Andrew а   че   на   дебаге  будет  быстрей  ??

Comment: Потому что дебаг имеет дополнительный код при компиляции для того, что бы ты мог дебажить. А у тебя действий между которыми нужен дополнительный код значительно больше чем у меня.

Comment: а   понятно________________________

Answer (score -1):

```
Sprite[] m_sprites;
int m_currentSpriteIndex;
SpriteRenderer m_spriteRenderer;

void OnClick()
{
    IncreaseIndex();
    UpdateSprite();        
}

void IncreaseIndex()
{
    m_currentSpriteIndex = UtilityArray.GetNextArrayElement(
        m_currentSpriteIndex, m_sprites.Length);
}
void UpdateSprite()
{
    m_spriteRenderer.sprite = m_sprites[m_currentSpriteIndex];
}

public static class UtilityArray
{
    public static int GetNextArrayElement(int current, int arrayLength)
    {
        return
            (++current < arrayLength)
            ? current : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Comment: @Splashny зачем вы принимаете ответ, если вы его не поняли, а значит априори не можете знать, верный он или нет?

Comment: @Slavik причем здесь работает или нет, я спросил, зачем принимать, если человек не понял ответа. Что касается конкретно вашего ответа: имхо это решение хуже, чем решение @Andrew, т.к. использует if (даже если jit додумается использовать `cmov` вместо джампов). И проблема тут даже не в производительности, а в целом в подходе. Я ни разу не видел, чтобы в таких задачах использовался остаток от деления. **P.S.** это мое мнение, я не берусь судить ответ, минус я ставить тоже не собираюсь, т.к. глобально тернарный оператор или остаток от деления сути не поменяют.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker прошу прощения

Comment: @RiotBr3aker  ну  не поменяют  значит используй  деление дальше,  и  не  важно  что  выполняется  оно  раз в 10 дольше обыкновенных, простых операций

Comment: @RiotBr3aker тебе я  так понял лишь бы  поменьше кода писать  )

Comment: @RiotBr3aker даи знаешь я лучше доверюсь книжке, чем какому то "программисту"  с  форума

Comment: @Splashny  ну  так  если  не  понимаешь  этого   тогда  мои обьяснения ничем не помогут

Comment: @Slavik условный переход с каких-то пор быстрее деления? Держи в курсе :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker ну а ты что думал, конечно быстрее